# How to observe Changes in Shared Preference using LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-livedata

Recently, I had a requirement in one of my projects to observe the changes in SharedPreferences throughout my app (I had activity, Foreground Service and BroadcastReciever which would react differently to changes in SharedPreferences). I also wanted to listen for these changes only when my corresponding AppComponents are active. As such, LiveData would be what will suit my requirement but what would be the best approach to do so?

(Asking the question for documentation purpose, would love to see any better implementation than one in the answer below )

Answer (score 5):

The following  piece of code is LiveData Implementation of SharedPreference that i have been using in my projects. It works well.

```
package com.chargingwatts.chargingalarm.util.preference;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.content.SharedPreferences

abstract class SharedPreferenceLiveData<T>(val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences,
                                           val key: String,
                                           val defValue: T) : LiveData<T>() {

    private val preferenceChangeListener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
        if (key == this.key) {
            value = getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)
        }
    }

    abstract fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: T): T

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        value = getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)
        sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        sharedPrefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
        super.onInactive()
    }
}

class SharedPreferenceIntLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Int) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Int>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Int): Int = sharedPrefs.getInt(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: String) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<String>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: String): String = sharedPrefs.getString(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Boolean) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Boolean): Boolean = sharedPrefs.getBoolean(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceFloatLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Float) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Float>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Float): Float = sharedPrefs.getFloat(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceLongLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Long) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Long>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Long): Long = sharedPrefs.getLong(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceStringSetLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Set<String>) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Set<String>>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Set<String>): Set<String> = sharedPrefs.getStringSet(key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.intLiveData(key: String, defValue: Int): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Int> {
    return SharedPreferenceIntLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.stringLiveData(key: String, defValue: String): SharedPreferenceLiveData<String> {
    return SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.booleanLiveData(key: String, defValue: Boolean): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean> {
    return SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.floatLiveData(key: String, defValue: Float): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Float> {
    return SharedPreferenceFloatLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.longLiveData(key: String, defValue: Long): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Long> {
    return SharedPreferenceLongLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.stringSetLiveData(key: String, defValue: Set<String>): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Set<String>> {
    return SharedPreferenceStringSetLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}
```